# Do we know anything about how Neuromancer was edited?

Tags: neuromancer, william-gibson, editors

William Gibson’s *Neuromancer* has somewhat of a reputation for being a challenging read. While some of this is due to neologisms and dense prose, reading the book left me with the impression that many of the intelligibility issues could be addressed with minimal editing (more likely by a professional editor rather than the author himself), in particular without considerably affecting the style.

I thus wonder whether we know anything about how it was edited that might confirm or refute this. I vaguely remember some third-hand information that the book was rushed, but that’s about it. [The cover of the first edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Neuromancer_(Book).jpg) says *edited by Terry Carr,* but we don’t know whether the latter just commissioned the book or actually touched/criticised the content.

Comment: Is it really a challenging read?

Comment: In interviews over the years, Gibson has talked a lot about the creation and production processes for *Neuromancer*.  I'll see if I can locate what he might have had to say about the publisher's editing process.

Comment: Funny - I’ve never heard this. I had a much harder time reading Dune and Lord of the Rings and never got past the first chapter of Foundation. Neuromancer is super easy to get through by comparison. There’s some vague stuff with Linda Lee and Terzibasjian but those moments aren’t that central to the story

Comment: Having done a web search on it being hard to read, I’m fascinated and also wondering if it’s not the writing but maybe the context. Maybe a lot of things in the book make more sense if you’re reading it in the middle of the 1980s as opposed to today. The web didn’t exist then, and hackers were things that hardly anyone hard heard about. Gibson invented a vague concept of what computers might be like in the future from an 80s perspective. Trying to understand a lot of the concepts for someone born in the last 25-30 years might be a big challenge. I bet the pay phone scene is hard to get today.

Comment: @ToddWilcox _"I bet the pay phone scene is hard to get today."_ Nah, there was one in The Matrix. But then again, that's 20 years ago.

Comment: Compare with the seed story, [Burning Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Chrome) which has all of the "Neuromancer" stylism going. There is the even earlier [Johnny Mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mnemonic), which is much flatter. Maybe the section [Literary and cultural significance of Neuromancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromancer#Literary_and_cultural_significance) can be exploited for this question,

Comment: Most likely it was edited to make it exactly the way it is. It’s not like they didn’t know Gibson was hard to read.